# AngularJS Toaster doesn't work with state.go

Tags: angularjs, state, router, toast

I have a problem with this component . If I open the page directly , you see the warning. If I arrive at the page from another page do not.

ROUTER:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: "assets/views/login.html",
    resolve: loadSequence('modernizr', 'moment', 'sweet-alert', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert', 'toaster'),
    abstract: true
}).state('login.lockscreen', {
    url: '/lock',
    templateUrl: "assets/views/login_lock_screen.html",
    title: 'Lock screen',
    resolve: loadSequence('userLoginCtrl')
});
```

Factory for Alert:

```
'use strict';
app.factory("alertGenerate", ["toaster", function(toaster) {
return {
    show: function(options) {
        console.log("SHOW ALERT");
        console.log(options);
        /*
         *  TOASTER
         */
        var config = {
            type: options.type,
            title: options.title,
            body: options.text
        };
        if(options.confirmButtonText || options.showCloseButton) {
            config.showCloseButton = true;
        }
        toaster.pop(config);
    }
}
}]);
```

CONTROLLER:

```
app.controller('UserLoginCtrl', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$auth", "$http", "$state", "$filter", "alertGenerate", function ($rootScope, $scope, $auth, $http, $state, $filter, alertGenerate) {

alertGenerate.show({
    type: 'error',
    title: 'Title text',
    body: 'Body text',
    showCloseButton: true,
    closeHtml: '<button>Close</button>'
});
```

login.html (abstract)

```
<!-- toaster directive -->
<toaster-container toaster-options="{'position-class': 'toast-bottom-right', 'close-button':true}"></toaster-container>
<!-- / toaster directive -->
<div ui-view class="fade-in-right-big smooth"></div>
```

login_lock_screeen.html

```
<!-- start: LOCK SCREEN -->
<div class="row">
<div class="lock-screen">
hello
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try `$state.go('state', {} , { reload: true })` ?

Comment: Already try it but it doesn't work.

Comment: another guess is that  maybe the toaster is outside the scope of the child view. can you try to put it inside the ui-view ?

Comment: If I put in ui-view it is overwrited when I load another view. :(

Comment: sorry, try inside the templates that are loaded in the ui-view. does it work then?

Comment: Does not work. From the same problem: the directive of Toaster element is filled, but you do not receive alerts.